# cant get the sound to play with pygame

Tags: python, timer, tkinter, pygame

I am working on a simple timer program. When the time is up, I have an alert window appear, and I would also would like to have a song play with it. From what i have gathered on using pygame.mixer, it should work, but my audio is not playing. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("alarm.mp3")


def messageWindow():
        win = Toplevel()
        b = Button(win, text='Times Up!',
                bg="yellow", fg="green",
                activebackground="purple", activeforeground="white",
                command=quit)
        b.pack(ipadx=root.winfo_screenwidth()/2,
                ipady=root.winfo_screenheight()/2)

        root.mainloop()

def alert():
        Sound.play()
        messageWindow()
        quit()

def start():
        root.after(scale.get() * 1000, alert)

root = Tk()

minutes = Label(root, text ="Minutes:  ")
minutes.grid(row=0, column=0)

scale = Scale(root, from_=1, to=60, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=450)
scale.grid(row=0, column=1)

button = Button(root,text= "Start Timing", command=start)
button.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I assume you have checked volume :)
Have you tried different formats - ogg, wav ?

Comment: no, I haven't tried different formats. Would that make a difference? from what i understand, it should work with mp3

Comment: switched it to .wav, and it worked. Weird. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, pygame doesn't have built-in compatibility with .mp3 files, but there are a number of other ways you can play audio.

For mp3s specifically, there is the mp3play package, which you could use like this:

```
import mp3play
filename = "C:/PATH/TO/FILE.mp3"
sound = mp3play.load(filename)
sound.play()
```

(This module can be downloaded from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mp3play/0.1.15#downloads)

If you are writing your program on Windows, you can also use the winsound module, as follows:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound("C:/PATH/TO/FILE.mp3")
```

Other options are the Snack Sound Toolkit (http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/) and the PyMedia package.

Comment: thanks. I was aware of those other packages, but i am working in linux mint. Thanks for the info. I am just going to use .wav from now on.